# Finding K largest numbers using counting sort in unsorted array

Tags: c, counting-sort

I am learning how to implement counting sort properly by doing some small online tasks. I wrote the code but it gives me segmentation fault for some reason. There is one testing input which can be seen:
n=6, k=4 
8 9 5 1 4 2 
n = number of prices 
k = number of prices which I want to make sum of 
So output for this case will be 26 (because 9+8+5+4) 
But there is also one secret test where I dont see the input and when I try to test it, it gives "segmentation fault".

I tried to use malloc so I dont have to define MAX_BUFFER, but it did not help me.

```
int *countings;
int *sorted;

max = price[0];

    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {                          
        if (max < price[i]) {
            max = price[i];
        }
    } 
countings = (int*)malloc(max * sizeof(int));
sorted = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

This is the full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER 100

long sum_of_k_biggest_numbers(int price[], int n, int k)
{
    int max; 
    int i;
    int countings[MAX_BUFFER];
    int sorted[MAX_BUFFER];
    int final_price = 0;

    max = price[0];

    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {                          
        if (max < price[i]) {
            max = price[i];
        }
    } 
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {                          
        countings[price[i]]++;
    } 
    for (i=1; i<(max+1); i++) {
        countings[i] += countings[i - 1];
    } 
    for (i=(n-1); i>=0; i--) {                     
        sorted[--countings[price[i]]] = price[i]; 
    } 
    for (i=(n-1); i>=(n-k); i--) {                 
        final_price += sorted[i];
    }

    return final_price;
}

int main(void)
{
  int i, *x, n, k;

  scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
  x = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &x[i]);

  printf("%ld\n", sum_of_k_biggest_numbers(x, n, k));
  return 0;
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint or tell me, where might be the problem?

Comment: Use a debugger, set a break point at the start of your code, and step through it.

Comment: If any array value is `< 0 ` or `>= MAX_BUFFER` you will break the array index for `countings`. But since `countings` array is uninitialised, and you are incrementing its elements, you'll **very likely** break the array `sorted`. Put in some range checking to find where it goes wrong. Using `malloc` instead of a defined array, won't help.

Comment: Try `int countings[MAX_BUFFER] = {0};`

Comment: @Abdulkareem I hope you mean `{ 0 }` .

Comment: @Weather Vane yes its updated, when i becomes 7 then `countings[i] += countings[i - 1];` tries to access uninitialized array element